# Regarding installation of nasm

Tags: networking

I have installed nasm in Ubuntu but I'm getting an error

```
$ ld -o file file.o
i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this command: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is running 32 bit apps on a 64 bit machine. Try setting elf_i386 while linking:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -o file.o file
```